# Symfony console ProgressBar component is not displayed in composer scripts

Tags: php, progress-bar, composer-php, symfony-console

Using the [ProgressBar component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) in a command called by a [composer script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) has no effect as the ProgressBar output is not shown.

Why is this? Is there a way to enforce its rendering?

---

Update: Now (since upgrade to symfony 2.6) it is shown, but the console refresh doesn't work correctly and for each update is adds a new line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're using a up-to-date version of the component.
Check if the bar works correct with the following snippet:

```
<?php
$max=10;
$progress = new ProgressBar($output, $max);
$progress->start();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $max; ++$i) {
 sleep(1);
 $progress->advance();
}
$progress->finish();
```

If this is the case, the task you execute between every `$progress->advance();` step seems to write something to output which makes the bar be redrawn on every step.